# How to get a site's URL by its title in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to link to a given site's Documents Library, I know I simply need to append the `/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx` to the site URL, however how can I get that site URL with just its title?

I've tried using `_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('<Page Title>')/` but I get an error saying that the list does not exist in the site even though I can veryify in the site configuration that is indeed the title.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't completely sure what you were trying to do based on your question; but after reading the answer you provided, you need use the OData **$filter** query option:

```
function setDepartmentLink(department){
    $.ajax({
        url: "_api/web/webs?$select=Url&$filter=Title eq '" + department + "'",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.d.results.length > 0){
                  $("#SPDDeptFolderLink").text(department).prop("href", encodeURI(data.d.results[0].Url + "/Shared Files/Forms/AllItems.aspx"));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the correct name of the list

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('listname')/Items
```

The above api will result the all items in a list.

OR try with GUID of the list

```
/_api/Web/Lists(guid'guid id of your list')
```

If you are looking for list guid,

1.Go to the list in the site

2.Click the LIST or LIBRARY tab and click LIST/LIBRARY Settings

3.Look in the browser’s address bar and you will see something like this:

```
http://yourserver/sites/training/_layouts/listedit.aspx?List=%7B81588B61%2D860D%2D4487%2DB81F%2DA1846A37954B%7D
```

4.Copy everything after the “List=” and paste into Notepad

You should now have something like this in Notepad:

```
%7B81588B61%2D860D%2D4487%2DB81F%2DA1846A37954B%7D
```

5.The GUID you copied is encoded. You now need to clean this up

1.Delete the “%7B” at the beginning

2.Delete the “%7D” at the end

3.Do a search and replace and change “%2D” to “-“  (a dash)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it with the following method:

```
function setDepartmentLink(department){
        $.ajax({
        url: "_api/web/webs",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            data.d.results.forEach(function (site) {
                if(site.Title === department){
                        $("#SPDDeptFolderLink").text(department).prop("href", encodeURI(site.Url + "/Shared Files/Forms/AllItems.aspx"));
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Since I wasn't able to find a method that returned a site's URL given its title I decided to iterate over all the sites and simply look for the title.